# Regex to convert already formatted date to different format

Tags: php, regex, time, preg-replace, str-replace

I have `$date = $run['at'];`, which gives me *2013-06-03T16:52:24Z*. How can I manipolate it to get for example "`d M Y, H:i`" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the DateTime class.

```
$date = new DateTime($run['at']);
echo $date->format('d M Y, H:i');
```

Comment: Is it better than strtotime?

Comment: Is different. Is an object oriented way to deal with dates and very flexible. The DateTime and DateInterval classes are very powerful. Requires PHP 5 >= 5.2.0

Comment: Actually strtotime gives me  03 Jun 2013, 18:52. DateTime gives me 03 Jun 2013, 16:52 (2 hours difference).

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno that sounds like a TimeZone or DST issue. Check your php.ini for the default timezone you are using and you can var_dump your DateTime object to see what time zone is using, should match the one on you php.ini. In any case you can change the timezone. For more info visit here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: This is the better answer for sure. Although I wonder where you get that datetime from and if it your source can't be improved. If it comes from MySQL, it probably can

Comment: Can I ask you how to do this with strftime? Because I need to have date in a language different than English and strftime is the only who "accepts" set_locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$time = strtotime($run['at']);
echo date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

But, where does `$run['at']` come from?

Comment: Sorry. Here I am. It came from a JSON input :)

Comment: And where does the JSON come from? :-)

Comment: BTW I was getting this with strtotime: "PHP Warning:  strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" :)